# Preferable way to send notification for task list. Timer job or workflow?

Tags: 2010, workflow, email, timer-jobs, task-list

I am new to sharepoint.

I am having a task list in which I want to send e-mails to the person whom the task is assigned before 24 hours of due date.

I am confused whether to use workflow or timer job? to perform this query.

Is other better way available rather than timer job or workflows?

Answer (score 1):

Workflow can be triggered when an item is updated, created or deleted. In this case (before 24 hours of due date) you cannot use it. You should use timer job service. In sp2013 you can use a new kind of workflow that can be run as repeatable workflow.

Comment: In the case if I am using SP2013 will it be preferable to go through the workflow or use timer job?

Comment: @RiyazKalva, If you would like to use this functionality only on one site, I think,  you can try to use workflow. But I don't know its restrictions. For many sites timer job will be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

A workflow can most definitely be used for this purpose. You can setup a workflow to start on item creation and update. For the workflow use the following:

*Calculate* Current Item:Due Date *minus* 86400 (*Output to* Variable: calc)
*then Pause until* Variable: calc
*then Email* these users

**When entering in the Current Item:Due Date field**, select it as Number of Seconds since 00:00:00 1/1/1900

This should create a date 24 hours (60 seconds * 60 minutes * 24 hours = 86400) and store it in a variable calc that the workflow will stop until. Once it hits that date, it should send out the email.

Comment: I don't know about sp2013, but in 2010 you have a big issue with suspend activity. Some times, the workflow can be started, some times not. There is an update package on the internet, but it works randomly.